# UIView with iOS 7 not showing up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have an app I was building for iOS 6 that I recently upgraded to iOS 7. I have a `UIScrollView` with a Custom `UIView`. Inside that, I have 4 custom `UIViews`. For some reason, these views show up fine on iOS 6, but iOS 7 they will not show them. I've tried: `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

As I said, it shows up fine in iOS 6. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: have tried checking off autolayouts? it must be either an autolayout or an nsconstraint thing

Comment: So all the views are not showing in IOS 7 is it?

Comment: one question. You have integrated your scrollview using xib or programmatically?

Comment: yes. Nire Mukund shah is right... If you integrated the scroll view using xib means you need to fix the status bar issue in IOS 7 as well.

Comment: @abbood - I need to use auto layout.

Comment: I've integrated the scrollview in Storyboard, but I set the content size programmatically in my `ViewController` under `viewDidAppear`. As I said, it works no problem in iOS 6, but not in iOS 7.